# How to display datepicker by week?

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

[image]

Is it possible to do this with jQuery Datepicker ?

Or another plugin ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use jquery [Datetimepicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)

In this plugin

Answer (score 1):

you can try the [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io) which has the day/week/month view. OR use the [bootstrap datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) in which you can select the time and date as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use A Basic Weekly Schedule with Hour Selector Using jQuery :

http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Create-A-Basic-Weekly-Schedule-with-Hour-Selector-Using-jQuery.html

You can see **[Demo](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Create-A-Basic-Weekly-Schedule-with-Hour-Selector-Using-jQuery/)** and **[Download](http://www.jqueryscript.net/download/Create-A-Basic-Weekly-Schedule-with-Hour-Selector-Using-jQuery.zip)**